# Loading additional dependencies from nuget source via config

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

i want to create a hosting environment with mvc 6 that is able to load plugins at runtime. Which means i need to load additional dependencies from a nuget source via config with vnext/asp.net 5.0. I have done this before with the nuget core libraries, but this obsolete with asp.net 5. That's why i'd like to use the build in dependency resolvers in vnext.

I had a look on the following websites to get an idea about the new framework, but after days of researching i came to a dead end.

https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/tree/f34c09233eb7b776c18d160f225a2ef9a0ef9d89/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime/DependencyManagement

http://blog.alxandr.me/2014/08/05/vnext-with-a-touch-of-functional/

Is there anybody out there with more experencie on vnext?

Comment: You want to download NuGet packages while the application is running? Are you really sure about this?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to update existing plugins and/or add new plugins on application start.